# How do i connect EC2 instance for elastic search in Django?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I'm just trying to add dynamic search as a feature to my application, i used Django Elasticsearch DSL to achieve this https://django-elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html, but i'm not able to connect the running postgres EC2 instance. Any leads would be very much appreciated :)

Here is the snippet where i have to add the creds -

```
    ELASTICSEARCH_DSL={
    'default': {
        'hosts': 'localhost:9200'
    },
}
```

Currently, i'm accessing the EC2 using username, password, of-course Host and Port address.

Comment: elasticsearch is not postgres... You will need to install elasticsearch on your server and configure it.

Comment: @brian, Postgres is already running on one of my  EC2 instance and it’s creds have been configured in DATABASES variable in settings.py  file , for elastic search I have to configure the host address in above mentioned variable as well!

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))) caused by: ProtocolError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))), This is the error i'm receiving!